# Spock - Pass test successfully after timeout

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock

In Spock, you can set time out, after which the test fails.

```
@Timeout(value = 1500, unit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
def "this method should not run longer than 2 seconds"() {
    given:
    userFilter = buildUserFilter(); // criteria to search users.
    exportDestination = buildDestination(); // where to export users.

    expect: "should not take long"
    userService.exportUsers(userDetails);
}
```

Now I need something the opposite: the test should pass after timeout.

```
def "should block and wait until user-microservice is up"() {
    given:
    userExportMicroserviceClient = mock()
    userExportMicroserviceClient.getUsers(_) >> httpNotFound

    expect: "should block the current thread because userMicroservice is down"
    failHere()
}
```

I know, it is a bad thing to depend on the other service availability. This thing runs only during data migration and it is not related to daily tasks.

Again, I have a method that gives users from user microservice, and it blocks until user microservice is up. How do I test it?

Comment: There are several ways I might misunderstand what you want. Please update your question with a working example ([MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) which actually makes sense and illustrates what you want. I need something I can compile and run. Pseudo-code with missing dependencies is not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how did you implement the `exportUsers()` method.
Assume it pulls a microservice every second. If so, you can emulate the response of the microservice in sequence: down, down, up.

```
// The timeout includes 2 seconds of microservice down.
@Timeout(value = 3500, unit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
def "should block and wait until user-microservice is up"() {
    given: "mocked microservice which is not available for first 2 calls and available on 3rd call"
    userExportMicroserviceClient = mock()
    userExportMicroserviceClient.getUsers(_) >>> [httpNotFound, httpNotFound, httpOk]

    when: "calling the user getting should take long time"
    def actualResult = userService.exportUsers(userDetails)

    then:
    def expectedResult = <prepare>
    actualResult == expectedResult
}
```

Sure things, this is a pseudo-code and requires yours project specific corrections.

Comment: This is how I did!